# Effect of mutation on phenotype

Tags: dna, proteins, mutations, amino-acids

Is there a type of mutation that changes the phenotype of an organism, but not the protein sequence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It is actually the case of most mutations that affect the phenotype!

Only 1.5% of the human genome codes for proteins. About 5-10% of the human genome are regulatory sequences which do not produce any protein but greatly impact the phenotype by regulating the expression of coding sequences. A mutation in a regulatory sequence does not directly impact the protein sequence but can have drastic impact on the phenotype (and fitness).

There are a lot of such mutations that have been identified. Here are a few quick examples

- [Variation in Vertebrate Cis-Regulatory Elements in Evolution and Disease](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4215174/)
- [A cis-Regulatory Mutation of PDSS2 Causes Silky-Feather in Chickens](http://journals.plos.org/plosgenetics/article?id=10.1371/journal.pgen.1004576)
- [A regulatory mutation in IGF2 causes a major QTL effect on muscle growth in the pig](https://search.proquest.com/docview/204504458?pq-origsite=gscholar)
- [Blue eye color in humans may be caused by a perfectly associated founder mutation in a regulatory element [..]](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00439-007-0460-x)

Comment: Do you have a reference for the statement that most phenotypic changes are caused by mutations in regulatory sequences? And what is the definition of 'regulatory sequence' in the context of the 5-10% number?

Comment: @Remi - Nice answer.

Comment: @AlanBoyd: Read the cired papers. For silky feathers, "The causative mutation is located 103 base pairs upstream of the coding sequence of prenyl (decaprenyl) diphosphate synthase, subunit 2" which is a regulatory protein.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I wasn't really asking about specific examples - obviously these exist - I was asking for a supporting reference for the 'most mutations' statement.

Comment: @AlanBoyd - Ah, sorry.